# Delegatecall reverting after adding a second argument

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

solidity 0.8.3;

I am trying to implement delegatecall, and I created a simple test within my contracts.

```
function f(uint256 _testInt) public view returns(uint256 test) {
        test = _testInt + 1;
    }
```

When I call it like so:

```
(bool success0, bytes memory result0) = contract.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("f(uint256)", 1));
```

It works as expected. But if I change it to this:

```
function f(uint256 _testInt, uint256 _testInt2) public view returns(uint256 test) {
    test = _testInt + _testInt2;
}
```

and call it as such:

```
    (bool success0, bytes memory result0) = contract.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("f(uint256, uint256)", 1, 2));
```

Then it reverts without a reason string.
Won't even run the code.

Any thoughts?
I have tried playing with it a lot, but it seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the space here:

```
"f(uint256, uint256)"
```

to

```
"f(uint256,uint256)"
```